# drupal 7 : add 'updated by ' to admin content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

The default admin content view display:

> the author of the node

and

> the date of the last update

but not

> the person that did the last update.

Is it possible to add this information ( the logged-in user that modify the content) for any content type ?

Answer (score 2):

This method requires that node revision is enabled for the content type you want to apply this feature to.

To enable node revisions for `article` content type; Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/article`. and under `Publishing options` make sure that `Create new revision` is enabled.

To get `the person that did the last update`

```
$revisions = node_revision_list($node);
$lastUpdatedAuthorUid = $revisions[0]['uid'];
$lastUpdatedAuthorName = $revisions[0]['name'];
```

Comment: thanks ! How could i add this info for each entry of admin/content ?